# Rest API to update a library item giving 400 error

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, pnp-js-core

The code am using:

```
pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("Shared%20Documents").files.getByName("test.jpg").getItem().then(item => {

      item.update({
          Title: "A Title",
          tag2: "My Other Value"
      });
    })
```

error : The property 'tag2' does not exist on type 'SP.Data.Shared_x0020_DocumentsItem'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.

**NOTE: INTERNAL NAME DOES NOT WORK TOO!**

Comment: do you have the column with `internal name` "tag2" in that document library?

Comment: @GaneshSanap    yes i tried with the internal name ,it doesn't work

Comment: Try giving the url to library like this
`getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/mysite/Shared%20Documents")`

Comment: @AnkitKatiyar doesn't work too

Comment: Before updating the item check if the get request is working from the same code.'

Comment: @AnkitKatiyar yes the get request works

Comment: @Ankit Katiyar yes the get request works and in the response body  i only see the Title column and not tag1/tag2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue,i was using the wrong internal name. what i did was to go library setting-->select column-->Have a look at the link and look for field=something.

This was the wrong way of looking for the internal name. The correct way was

```
var item =pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("Shared%20Documents").files.getByName("test.jpg")

console.log(item)
```

You then consult the body of item to identify the correct internal name.